# null value in react conditional output

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I have this code in render in a component in React

```
{ record.updatedAt!==null && 
otherProps.moment(record.updatedAt).format("DD-MM-YYYY")}
```

record.updatedAt sometimes have null value , so in this case moment function give 'inValid Date' like output in that is printed.
To avoid this , i've added  record.updatedAt!==null, but i get this error:

```
but i keeping invalid date msg
```

any idea if my logic is right ?

UPDATE. it's working well when is null, don't conver, the problem is with the moment; if i print the value without moment i get:

```
Wed Nov 01 2017 12:22:04 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

Date come from postgresql time with zone, any idea how to convert it?

Comment: the problem i see is not with the null but when is null, null is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the check you are looking for is: (it looks like you are passing the moment library around as a prop)

```
{ otherProps.moment(record.updatedAt).isValid() && otherProps.moment(record.updatedAt).format("DD-MM-YYYY")}
```

From the moment docs:

> If a string does not match any of the above formats and is not able to
>   be parsed with Date.parse, moment#isValid will return false.

It all depends on how you are initializing this value - if its anything other than null before that value is a valid date you will always get that error...

Comment: i have this output:  Wed Nov 01 2017 12:22:04 GMT+0100 (CET), date come from postgresql time with zone, any idea how to convert it?